# Image loading with JQuery in Wicket

Tags: jquery, wicket

I'm trying to load images in wicket using an effect similar to [this](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/image-load-demo.php). This is what I'm currently doing:

In my image component (a simple panel that contains an image):

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.renderJavaScriptReference(GlobalNames.JQUERY_URL);
    response.renderJavaScript("$(document).ready(function(){$(\"img.elementImage\").hide().fadeIn(600);});", null);
}
```

And the html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html
    xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
<body>
<wicket:panel>
    <img class="elementImage" wicket:id="img"/>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this should do it, but I keep getting the error *$("img.elementImage") is null*. I tried also using a markup id instead of the class in the javascript and using other methods to add the javascript such as renderOnDomReadyJavaScript, but I get always the same error. This is the first time I use JQuery with Wicket, so it could be something really simple I'm missing though, any ideas?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded properly? As for the jQuery selector it is enough to select `$(".elementImage")`. Try when the Page is loaded from Firefox or Chrome Webconsole to select the image using jQuery. Take also a look at `AjaxLazyLoadPanel`: http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/how-do-use-ajaxlazyloadpanel-in-wicket/ - this might solve your use case without jQuery, although i havent used it.

Comment: The wicked:id="img" wont actually be rendered as id="img". Wicket normally adds a number to the end of the id. For example id="img12", its in the documentation somewhere, but they tell you to never use the wicket:id in a selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, it is solved. Turns out JQuery was in conflict with some other script added before, so the '$' didn't work in the selector. I used jQuery(img.elementImage) instead and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the responses!